# How to forward mails in lotus notes

Tags: lotus-notes

As per title, how can I forward all the emails I’m receiving?

I have tried the rules option, but I can’t select all the incoming mails and I cannot find an appropriate action to forward to another email.

Comment: Does [Open Notebook: How to automatically forward emails to other accounts in Lotus Notes](https://hongqinlab.blogspot.com/2013/11/how-to-automatically-forward-emails-to.html) answer your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a simple way to forward everything with a rule:
[image]

Condition: "all documents", Action: "send copy to"

The screenshot is from an original 9.0.1 english mail template from 2013, I am not sure, if the options were available in 8.5.x as well, but at least since 8 years this is working.

If the "send copy to" part is not working, then the admin has disallowed forwarding rules in the server configuration.

If the "send copy to" or "all documents" part is completely missing, then probably some design changes have been made to the template to disable this option as there is no way to "hide" it using policies/ sth. else: these options are hard coded in that fields.